# spinner dropdown arrow icon not visible inside below UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-tablelayout, android-relativelayout

I placed a spinner inside TableRow in TableLayout. Spinner dropdown icon not visible.

Table 1:
       I place a spinner inside table row, But my spinner dropdown arrow not visible inside table row

Table 2:
       I have placed spinner inside Relative Layout which is inside Table Row, In this scenario also spinner drop down not visible and in UI screen spinner width exceed Relative Layout.

How can I fix the spinner fixed into the width with drop down icon visible?What's wrong with below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TableRow style="@style/HeaderRow"
            android:weightSum="10">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_white"
                style="@style/HeaderText" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Information"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                style="@style/HeaderText"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_white"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TableRow style="@style/HeaderRow"
            android:weightSum="10">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_white"
                style="@style/HeaderText" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Information"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_white"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                style="@style/HeaderText"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_white"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Style.xml

```
<style name="HeaderRow">
    <item name="android:background">#A3A3A3</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>
<style name="HeaderText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_white</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#AFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1.0</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/border</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

[image: Output Of layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have added `TableRow` `weightsum` value as **10** then all child views `layout_weight` values sum should also be **10**.

For example;

```
 <TableRow
        style="@style/HeaderRow"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/HeaderText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Information"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            style="@style/HeaderText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4" />
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TableRow>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_white"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Information"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_white"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Information"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_white"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5">

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_white"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Information"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

 </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this help you...if you need any help you can ask

Comment: Where is spinner in your answer?

Comment: @appukrb check it